# PowerShell optimize Rename-Item -NewName using Split method

Tags: powershell, rename, file-rename, rename-item-cmdlet

In short I'm inserting a hardcoded value 'USA' into the middle of the file name. My code currently works however I feel like it could be optimized, maybe by using `-replace` operator and RegEx or less returned values (everything before the 4th delimiter '.' + 'USA' + everything after) rather than returning 12 values (0 position + '.' + 1 position + '.' + 2 position + '.' + 3 position + '.' + 'USA' + '.' + 4 position + $_.Extension). Or maybe using the Insert method after the 4th delimiter?  I'm iterating through a directory that has several hundreds of subfolders and renaming the '.xlsx' files in the '2023' subfolders. There is usually a folder within '2023' called 'Misc'. I don't want to rename those '.xlsx' files, just the ones in '2023'. I'm sure I can even tighten this up and only look for '.xlsx' files that have 4 '.' in the filename (not inlcuding file entension or new value, 'USA') so I'm not renaming other '.xlsx' files with '.' in the file name.

Current file naming convention: comp_id.process_id.comp_name.state.date.xlsx

Ex: 12345.001.chris_comp.NY.2023_08_22.xlsx

Desired filename naming convention, insert hardcoded value 'USA' after the 4th delimiter '.' so it would look like this: comp_id.process_id.comp_name.**USA**.date.xlsx

Ex: 12345.001.chris_comp.NY.**USA**.2023_08_22.xlsx

```
#renameFile
$numberedFolder = 'C:\Users\Documents\My Documents\PowerShell\Test'
$excludeFolder = 'Misc'
$delimiter = '.'
$excelFile = '.xlsx'
$search = Get-ChildItem -Path $nuberedFolder -Filter '2023' -Recurse
ForEach ($path in $search.fullname) {
Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Where-Object {($_.Extension -match $excelFile)} | 
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Split($delimiter)[0] + '.' + $_.Name.Split($delimiter)[1] + '.' + $_.Name.Split($delimiter)[2] + '.' + $_.Name.Split($delimiter)[3] + '.' + 'USA' + '.' + $_.Name.Split($delimiter)[4] + $_.Extension} -WhatIf
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) offers a concise solution:

```bash
... |
 Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(?:[^.]+\.){4}', '$&USA.' } -WhatIf
```

For an explanation of the regex and the substitution expression, along with the option to experiment with them, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/7dGfAC/1).

---

Furthermore, you can streamline your overall command as follows:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -LiteralPath $numberedFolder -Filter '2023' |
  Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*.*.*.*.*.xlsx' |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(?:[^.]+\.){4}', '$&USA.' } -WhatIf
```